# Random points on the unit sphere

Tags: pr.probability, combinatorial-geometry, integral-geometry

Suppose you have $n$ points picked uniformly at random on the surface of $\mathbb{S}^d,$ and let the volume of the convex hull of these points be $V_{n, d}.$ Clearly, $V_{n, d}$ converges to the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ as $n$ goes to infinity, but what is the distribution (or at least the expectation) of the difference? For $d=1,$ it is a simple computation that the $V_{n, 1} - \pi = O(1/n^3)\dots$

(there seem to be a number of questions and references about points in polygons, but I seem to be failing to find anything on spheres...)

Comment: Do simulations lead to a conjecture?

Comment: http://www.renyi.hu/~barany/cikkek/31.pdf
This is slightly different problem (points are chosen not on the surface, but inside a body),though seems intimately connected. Maybe, it makes sense to ask Imre Bárány directly.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.4978 and http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669807000650 consider more generally a boundary of a convex body instead of $\mathbb{S}^d$

Comment: @MoritzFirsching Very cool, that certainly answers it!

Comment: @MoritzFirsching If you give your comment as an answer, I will be happy to accept it...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this question has been answered for random pointes on the boundary of convex bodies and even better for all intrinsic volumes. Let me offer some references:

A good refernce is:

Matthias Reitzner, *Random points on the boundary of smooth convex bodies*, [Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 354, 2243-2278, 2002](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2002-354-06/S0002-9947-02-02962-8/home.html)

Abstract:

> The convex hull of $n$ independent random points chosen on the boundary of a convex body $K \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ according to a given density function is a random polytope. The expectation of its $i$-th intrinsic volume for $i=1, \dots, d$ is investigated. In the case that the boundary of $K$ is sufficiently smooth, asymptotic expansions for these expected intrinsic volumes as $n \to \infty$ are derived.

---

By Ross M. Richardson, Van H. Vu and  Lei Wu there are two papers, which are very simlilar:

*Random inscribing polytopes*, [European Journal of Combinatorics. Volume 28, Issue 8, Pages 2057–2071, November 2007](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669807000650)

and

*An Inscribing Model for Random Polytopes*, [Discrete & Computational Geometry, Volume 39, Issue 1-3, pp 469-499, March 2008](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-007-9012-3)

With the following abstract:

> For convex bodies $K$ with $\mathcal{C}^2$ boundary in $\mathbb{R}^d$ , we explore random polytopes with vertices chosen along the boundary of $K$. In particular, we determine asymptotic properties of the volume of these random polytopes. We provide results concerning the variance and higher moments of this functional, as well as an analogous central limit theorem.

---

Another more recent reference is

Károly J. Böröczky, Ferenc Fodor, Daniel Hug, *Intrinsic volumes of random polytopes with vertices on the boundary of a convex body*, [Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 365, 785-809, 2013](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2013-365-02/S0002-9947-2012-05648-0/home.html), [arxiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.4978)

> Let $K$ be a convex body in $\mathbb{R}^d$, let $j\in\{1, ..., d-1\}$, and let
>   $\varrho$ be a positive and continuous probability density function with
>   respect to the $(d-1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure on the boundary $\partial
> K$ of $K$. Denote by $K_n$ the convex hull of $n$ points chosen randomly and
>   independently from $\partial K$ according to the probability distribution
>   determined by $\varrho$. For the case when $\partial K$ is a $C^2$ submanifold
>   of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with everywhere positive Gauss curvature, M. Reitzner proved an
>   asymptotic formula for the expectation of the difference of the $j$th intrinsic
>   volumes of $K$ and $K_n$, as $n\to\infty$. In this article, we extend this
>   result to the case when the only condition on $K$ is that a ball rolls freely
>   in $K$.

Comment: Cool answer. And *fantastic* profile picture!

Answer (score 5):

Average area (over $100$ trials) of $n$ points uniformly distributed on a unit-radius circle:

---

[image: CircArea]

---

One $n=6$ example:

---

[image]

---